# standard ingress for certificate management combined with istio

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, cert-manager

Currently [Istio does not support a fully automated certificate procedure](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/9030). The standard ingress does support this by means of cert-manager. Would it be possible to combine standard ingress configuration for certification management with istio for other stuff? What are the down-sides to this combination?

Comment: can't you use nginx ingress ? it cert manager manage automatic cetificate renewal and annotation and many more options are there

Comment: @HarshManvar Well..., that's what my question is about. I probably could use nginx-ingress, but why are people using istio upset about no 'direct istio support for auto-certificates'... would using e.g. nginx-ingress somehow conflict with istio!? And if so, how exactly?

Comment: oh okay got it then i would also like to know have to wait for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was discussed in [a blog post on Medium last fall](https://medium.com/ww-engineering/istio-part-ii-e219a2e771bb), actually.  I held onto the link because I too am interested in using nginx-ingress as the front-end, but then taking advantage of istio "for other stuff".  If it pans out for you, would love to hear.

Comment: To me it seems this two-tier approach becomes complex pretty quickly and I read somewhere it does not support 'sticky sessions'. For now, I am betting on a one-tier approach of istio only and I think they are getting closer at [solving the certificate stuff](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/11496).

Comment: [This article](https://kubedex.com/ingress/) nicely compares the various ingress tools. The link to the google sheet includes istio ingress as well.